# Obtain two barplots in the same graph ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 5), age = 1:25)
df2 <- data.frame(name = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 5), age = c(rep(1,5), rep(5,5), 1,12,3,2,1,1:5,6:10))
```

And I want to produce horizontal barplots like these:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(name = fct_reorder(name, age)) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = name, y = age)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#74D055FF", alpha = .6, width = .6) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()

df2 %>%
  mutate(name = fct_reorder(name, age)) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = name, y = age)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#481568FF", alpha = .6, width = .6) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

I would like to show them in the same figure: there should be a vertical line in correspondence of `age = 0`, and then the violet bars should go on one side and the green ones on the other (of course it will then be sorted only based on `age` of either `df1` or `df2`, as the descending order of `age` is not the same in both dataframes). I don't know how this type of plot it's called and how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to bind your datasets into one dataframe and add an identifier column for which I use `dplyr::bind_rows`. The identifier could then be mapped on the `fill` aes and the colors set via `scale_fill_manual`. Also I aggregated the data using `count` instead of relying on stacking:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2, .id = "id") %>%
  count(id, name, wt = age, name = "age") |>
  mutate(
    name = reorder(name, (id == 1) * age, sum),
    age = if_else(id == 2, -age, age)
  ) |>
  ggplot(aes(y = name, x = age, fill = id, group = 1)) +
  geom_col(alpha = .6, width = .6) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#74D055FF", "#481568FF")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: It works, thanks, but i would like some clarifications if possible. Is there a way to avoid the violet bars to have negative values (if I change `-age` to `age` the bars are stacked)? What does exactly `name = reorder(name, (id == 1) * age, sum)` do? Is `|>` an alternative to `%>%` and why did you use one over the other?

Comment: Hej Lisa.`|>` is the native pipe "shipped" with R. You could replace it with `%>%`. One advantage of `|>` is that it does not require to load a package. That's why I use it. To get rid of the negative axis text use `scale_x_continuous(labels = abs)` to convert to absolute values. Finally, `(id == 1) * age` sets values for id=2 to zero. And with `sum` this is a small little trick to order by age for `id=1`. Otherwise when using `fct_reorder` or `reorder` name will be ordered by the median or mean of both ids.