# Stack bars on top of the others in a horizontal barplot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Building on a previous ([Obtain two barplots in the same graph ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75174243/obtain-two-barplots-in-the-same-graph-ggplot2)) question, I would like to add more complexity to this plot.
Example dataset:

```
df1 <- data.frame(who = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 5), 
        age = 1:25)
df2 <- data.frame(who = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 5), 
        age = c(rep(1, 5), rep(5, 5), 1, 12, 3, 2,1, 1:5, 
                6:10))
df3 <- data.frame(who = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 4), 
        age = c(rep(2, 10), rep(3, 10)))
df4 <- data.frame(who = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 5), 
        age = c(rep(1, 5), rep(5, 5), 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1:5, 
                6:10))

myList <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
names(myList) <- c("df1", "df2", "df3", "df4")
```

What I would like to achieve is to have `age` from `df1` and `df3` on the right, and `age` from `df2` and `df4` on the left (which I tried to accomplish with `value = if_else((ID == "DF 2" | ID == "DF 4"), -age, age)` in `mutate()` below).
I would like the y-axis (`who`) to be sorted based on `df1$age` (which I tried with `who = reorder(who, (ID == "DF 1") * age, sum)` in `mutate()`).
Lastly, I would like `df3$age` and `df4$age` to be stacked on top of, respectively, `df1$age` and `df2$age`.
This is my code so far:

```
p <- dplyr::bind_rows("DF 1" = myList[["df1"]],
                      "DF 2" = myList[["df2"]],
                      "DF 3" = myList[["df3"]],
                      "DF 4" = myList[["df4"]],
                      .id = "ID") %>%
  count(ID, who, wt = age, name = "age") %>%
  arrange(match(ID, c("DF 1", "DF 2", "DF 3", "DF 4"))) 
  %>%
  mutate(who = reorder(who, (ID == "DF 1") * age, sum), 
    value = if_else((ID == "DF 2" | 
                       ID == "DF 4"), -age, age)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = who, x = age, fill = ID, group = 1)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack", alpha = .6, width = .6) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = abs) + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,1.4)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#74D055FF","#481568FF", 
                               "#F1ED6FFF", "#F1ED6FFF"),
                    breaks = c("DF 1", "DF 2", "DF 3", 
                               "DF 4")) +
  theme_bw()
```

Colours, values and grouping are fine, but the plot is not "split" in two (i.e., no values on the left side), and the data are not correctly stacked (maybe this has to do with the argument position of `geom_col`?)

Comment: I think you forgot to change the `x` argument in `aes` to `value` instead of `age`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that indeed solved it. But I don't get why I have to put value instead of age? Is it because in this way it uses the value of the age column?

Comment: With the `mutate` command you created a variable named `value` that is equal to `-age` for DF2/DF4 and to `age` for DF1/DF3.  For `ggplot` to take that into account, you need to assign this new variable to the `x` axis, not the original variable which is still always positive.